# what Jobs can I get without atpl?

Tags: ppl, cpl

I wonder what jobs I can get if I have ppl and cpl but no atpl?
is it possible to earn money from holding these licences?

Comment: Which country are you asking about?

Comment: This is not a duplicate as this question asks what work you can do on a CPL. It is completely different to what work you can do on a PPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  See FAR 119.1.  They have a list of other commercial operation you can do with a CPL but not an ATPL.